# Reduce the size of a SpriteKit Node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit, sknode

Im trying to change the scale of my Spritekit node and nothing is working.

Ive tried .setSize(), .xScale(), .yScale(), .size = CGSize(width: 0.5, heightL 0.5) etc

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: emojiLabelText)
    labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.xScale = 0.5
    labelNode.yScale = 0.5
    return labelNode

}
```

also in the view did load I tried this..

```
 if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 0.50,
                            height: 0.50)
        sceneView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

Comment: you should tag `sprite-kit` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to resize a `SKLabelNode`. To do so you can change the `fontSize` property:

```
labelNode.fontSize = 10
```